# setting up a grpc typescript client

Tags: typescript, grpc, grpc-node

I am trying to setup a GRPC client to communicate with my goLang backend. The server is setup but I am having a lot of issues setting up the Client. I found a decent example [here](https://www.giac.cc/posts/grpc-static-code-typescript/)

But I am still not able to declar my client server.

This was my attempt to setup the server but it cannot find any of the endpoints which make me believe it is wrong.

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as grpc from "@grpc/grpc-js";
import {TestRequest} from "./src/proto/api_pb";
import services from "./src/proto/api_grpc_pb";

const client = new grpc.Client(
    "localhost:8082",
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
)

const request = new TestRequest();
request.setName("Hello World");
```

--

I want to declare the client from the imported services
but in the IDE I see and error reading `api_grpc_pb has no default export`.

In the example link I sent it has something like

```
const client = new services.GreeterClient(
  "localhost:50051",
  grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);
```

Of course my name is different, and in the generated file I have `api_grpc_pb.js`.

```
exports.ApiServiceClient = grpc.makeGenericClientConstructor(ApiServiceService);
```

However that is not accessible.

Makefile

```
.PHONY: proto
proto: ## Generate protobuf code
# Compile proto files inside the project.
    protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=.

    protoc --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto \
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${PROJ_PATH}/form/node_modules/.bin/grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin \
        --plugin=protoc-gen-ts=${PROJ_PATH}/form//node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \
        --js_out=import_style=commonjs:${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto \
        --grpc_out=grpc_js:${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto \
        --ts_out=grpc_js:${PROJ_PATH}/form/proto \
        -I ${PROJ_PATH}/proto \
         ${PROJ_PATH}/proto/*.proto
```

package.json

```
"google-protobuf": "^3.21.0",
"grpc-tools": "^1.11.3",
"grpc-web": "^1.0.7",
"protoc-gen-grpc": "^2.0.3",
"protoc-gen-ts": "^0.8.5",
"ts-protoc-gen": "^0.15.0",
"grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts": "^5.3.2",
```

Here is the repo I am currently working in [grpc_attempt_2](https://github.com/drewjocham/mock_ide_questions/tree/grpc_attempt_2/form)

Any advice on how I can setup/run my GRPC typescript client would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a picture of where I think the client is suppose to be exported.

--- it has been brought to my attention my import might be wrong

It should look like this...

```
import {ApiServiceClient} from "./src/proto/api_grpc_pb";
```

However the methods are still not available. Here is a picture of what I am facing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not accessible"? How exactly are you trying to access `ApiServiceClient`, and what specifically happens when you do that?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I import the services via `import services from "./src/proto/api_grpc_pb"` and then try to access it but I also see in the IDE `api_grpc_pb has no default export`. I appears it is generating wrong?? I updated the question a little with what I just posted.

Comment: I got the import error to go away with some more tsconfig.json addition. However there is no client to export `export default new services.<I shuold have something here>`. This is very strange. It seems the code generation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked, they import the service client class using this line:

```
import { GreeterService } from "./my_generated_code/helloworld_grpc_pb";
```

In this case, `GreeterService` is the name of the service client class. In the generated code in this question, the service client class is named `ApiServiceClient`. So, you should use a similar import line:

```
import { ApiServiceClient } from "./src/proto/api_grpc_pb";
```

This should replace this import line in your client code file:

```
import services from "./src/proto/api_grpc_pb";`
```

---

In addition, you should not construct a `grpc.Client` object directly. That will not have the generated code for the service, so you will not be able to make any requests to any methods. You should instead construct the generated service client class:

```
const client = new ApiServiceClient(
    "localhost:8082",
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting. I think I have tried this but I did it again and faced the same issue. I attached a picture showing the result

Comment: The image you added doesn't even show an error. If the problem is with the TypeScript types, what is the corresponding code in the generated TypeScript file?